# Update the values of multiple keys

Tags: clojure

If you have a map or a collection of maps and you'd like to be able to update the values of several keys with one function, what the the most idiomatic way of doing this?

```
=> (def m [{:a 2 :b 3} {:a 2 :b 5}])
#'user/m
=> (map #(update-in % [:a] inc) m)
({:a 3, :b 3} {:a 3, :b 5})
```

Rather than mapping update-in for each key, I'd ideally like some function that operates like this:

```
=> (map #(update-vals % [:a :b] inc) m)
({:a 3, :b 4} {:a 3, :b 6})
```

Any advice would be much appreciated! I'm trying to reduce the number of lines in an unnecessarily long script.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Whenever you need to iteratively apply a fn to some data, `reduce` is your friend:

```
(defn update-vals [map vals f]
  (reduce #(update-in % [%2] f) map vals))
```

Here it is in action:

```
user> (def m1 {:a 2 :b 3})
#'user/m1
user> (update-vals m1 [:a :b] inc)
{:a 3, :b 4}
user> (def m [{:a 2 :b 3} {:a 2 :b 5}])
#'user/m
user> (map #(update-vals % [:a :b] inc) m)
({:a 3, :b 4} {:a 3, :b 6})
```

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to keep the behavior of update-in so that a missing key does not throw a null pointer exception.   `(update-in {} [:test] (fnil inc 0))
{:test 1}`

Comment: this is avery nice answer and highlights some of the beauty of learning clojure (also some of the brain-wrapping difficulty to a non-lisper)

Comment: Is there a way of keeping the behaviour of `update-in` when you pass `+ 10` instead of `inc` ? `(update-vals m [:a :b] + 10)` does not work

Comment: @Cotten: you could pass a function to get your desired behaviour `(update-vals m1 [:a :b] #(+ 10 %))`

Comment: `(defn update-vals [m ks & args]
  (reduce #(apply update-in % [%2] args) m ks))` is what you want

Comment: I cringe thinking how inefficient this is compared to mutable code :-)