# Idiomatic way to iterate over a map, 'changing' each value and returning a map?

Tags: dictionary, clojure, idioms

```
(def m {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
```

Let's say I want each value in `m` to be incremented. The only way I can think of to do that is

```
(into {}
      (map
        (fn [[key val]]
          [key (inc val)])
        m))
```

Is there a better way to do this? I need to do this a lot in my code and it looks kind of hacky. I really do need to use a map here (mostly for O(1) lookups, the key will be a UUID and the value a map), not a vector or a list.

Comment: this looks related: 
http://blog.jayfields.com/2011/08/clojure-apply-function-to-each-value-of.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638271/update-the-values-of-multiple-keys

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mapping a function on the values of a map in Clojure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676891/mapping-a-function-on-the-values-of-a-map-in-clojure)

Comment: Use fmap, answered previously: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3757598/67957

Answer (score 2):

Found something that looks good here: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce-kv.

```
(defn update-map [m f] 
  (reduce-kv (fn [m k v] 
    (assoc m k (f v))) {} m))
```

Then you can do

```
(update-map {:a 1 :b 2} inc)
```

to get

```
 {:a 2 :b 3}
```

If needed you can supply `k` to `f` or make a `update-key-values` function that takes in two functions `f` and `g` and applies them to the keys and values respectively.